# Как передать значение в модальное окно

Tags: html, bootstrap

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо в модальное окно передать значение из кнопки.
Я видел другие ответы на такой вопрос, но я не использую angular, только jquery, и ради одной страницы не хочеться его подключать.

Код

```
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Заголовок :lebedev:</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                  <a :href="invite" target="popup" onclick="window.open('1 или 2 или 3','name','width=450,height=650')"><button class="bestButtons">Добавить</button></a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px; padding-left: 15px">1</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px; padding-left: 15px">2</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px; padding-left: 15px">3</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе не указали что именно будете передавать и куда получать, какая версию бутстрапа, так что ответ уже под себя подстроите:

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // Берём название кнопки, по которой вызывали модалку
    const btnName = $(e.relatedTarget).text();

    // И вставляем его в саму модалку
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.modal-title').val(btnName);
});
```

Работать должно на версиях 3.2.0+